# How to update displayed text in Pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have a couple of text rects succesfully displayed. However the message that is to be written is assigned to the variable `msg`. If I set my script to change the value of `msg` after a couple of seconds it is changed but it does not change what my message change. I have a `pygame.display.update()` but it still doesnt work.

HORL.py

```
import pygame, sys, time, random, math
from functions import horl, number, starting, msg
from pygame.locals import QUIT
pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screenWidth = 800
screenHeight = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screenWidth , screenHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption('Higher or Lower')
pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load('sprites/icons/icon.ico'))

# fonts
pixel_serif = pygame.font.Font('fonts/pixelserif.ttf', 32)

# name
name = pixel_serif.render('Higher or Lower', True, 0)
namerect = name.get_rect()
namerect.center = (400, 75)

# backgrounds
eight_to_six = pygame.image.load('sprites/background/800x600.png')

# buttons 
higher = pygame.image.load('sprites/icons/highButton.png')
lower = pygame.image.load('sprites/icons/lowButton.png')

# text
message = pixel_serif.render(msg, True, 0)
msgrect = message.get_rect()
msgrect.center = (400, 300)
num = pixel_serif.render(str(starting), True, 0)
numrect = num.get_rect()
numrect.center = (400, 350)

hpressed = False
lpressed = False
running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(60)
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1 and hButton.collidepoint(mouse_pos) and hpressed == False:
                hpressed = True
                higher = pygame.image.load('sprites/icons/highPressed.png')
                horl('H')
            elif event.button == 1 and lButton.collidepoint(mouse_pos) and lpressed == False:
                lpressed = True
                lower = pygame.image.load('sprites/icons/lowPressed.png')
                horl('L')
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            time.sleep(1)
            higher = pygame.image.load('sprites/icons/highButton.png')
            lower = pygame.image.load('sprites/icons/lowButton.png')
            hpressed = False
            lpressed = False

    screen.blit((eight_to_six), (0, 0))
    screen.blit(name, namerect)
    screen.blit(message, msgrect)
    screen.blit(num, numrect)

    hButton = screen.blit(higher,(200,400))
    lButton = screen.blit(lower,(500,400))

    pygame.display.update()
```

functions.py

````
import pygame, time, random
from random import randint, choice

class color:
    white = '255, 255, 255'
    black = '0, 0, 0'
    red = '255, 0, 0'
    green = '0, 255, 0'

wins = 0
loss = 0
rounds = 0

starting = randint(0,13)
number = choice([i for i in range(0,13) if i not in [starting]])
msg = 'The starting number is'

def correct(yn):
    if yn == 'y':
        starting = number
        print('msg y')
        msg = 'Correct! The number is',number

    elif yn == 'n':
        starting = number
        print('msg n')
        msg = 'Incorrect! The Number is',number

def horl(opt):
    global number
    global wins
    global loss
    global msg
    if opt == 'H':
        if number > int(starting):
            correct('y')
            wins = wins + 1
        elif number < int(starting):
            correct('n')
            loss = loss + 1
    elif opt == 'L':
        if number < int(starting):
            correct('y')
            wins = wins + 1
        elif number > int(starting):
            correct('n')
            loss = loss + 1
        else:
            print(color.error + '\nSYNTAX ERROR' + color.normal)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the `msg` variable, the *Surface* that is rendered from that text does not magically update. You have to render the text again. And you must return the new message text from the function:

````py
def correct(yn):
    if yn == 'y':
        starting = number
        print('msg y')
        msg = f'Correct! The number is {number}'

    elif yn == 'n':
        starting = number
        print('msg n')
        msg = f'Incorrect! The Number is {number}'
    return msg

def horl(opt):
    global number
    global wins
    global loss
    global msg

    new_msg = ""
    if opt == 'H':
        if number > int(starting):
            new_msg = correct('y')
            wins = wins + 1
        elif number < int(starting):
            new_msg = correct('n')
            loss = loss + 1
    elif opt == 'L':
        if number < int(starting):
            new_msg = correct('y')
            wins = wins + 1
        elif number > int(starting):
            new_msg = correct('n')
            loss = loss + 1
        else:
            print(color.error + '\nSYNTAX ERROR' + color.normal)```

    return new_msg
````

```py
while running:
    clock.tick(60)
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1 and hButton.collidepoint(mouse_pos) and hpressed == False:
                hpressed = True
                higher = pygame.image.load('sprites/icons/highPressed.png')
                msg = horl('H')
                message = pixel_serif.render(msg, True, 0)  
            elif event.button == 1 and lButton.collidepoint(mouse_pos) and lpressed == False:
                lpressed = True
                lower = pygame.image.load('sprites/icons/lowPressed.png')
                msg = horl('L')
                message = pixel_serif.render(msg, True, 0)

        # [...]
```

Comment: Thank you, I am kind of new to pygame, I just assumed that `pygame.display.update()` would magically re-render the text.